# Plugin Builder Load data

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt, qt-designer

I am trying to re design a plugin to run multiple iterations of data loaded from a file. I am using QT creator to develop the GUI. How would I design a load data input box so users can select a data file and then run the plugin.

The plugin initially uses single coordinate inputs i wish to use multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QLineEdit and QPushButton, lets call them `path` and `btn`.

Create function like that:

```
def choose_file():
    dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
    fname = dialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Choose file to open")
    if fname:
        path.setText(fname)
```

Now connect this function to the `btn`:

```
btn.clicked.connect(choose_file)
```

This is how it works in most cases. If you want to use this path then just get it from the `path` widget:

```
input = path.text()
```